# Sum if the date difference is smaller than a value

Tags: r, dataframe, time

I have a database that contains the registers of errors of a series of machines, with their correspondent date. There are several kind of errors. Ie:

[initial data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZMUM.png)

```
          fechayhora        id tipo
1: 2017-03-21 11:03:00 A2_LR1_Z1  APF
2: 2017-05-03 10:34:00 A2_LR1_Z1  APF
3: 2017-05-17 08:52:00 A2_LR1_Z1  APF
4: 2017-05-17 10:46:00 A2_LR1_Z1  APF
5: 2017-05-17 14:23:00 A2_LR1_Z1  APF
6: 2017-05-17 17:29:00 A2_LR1_Z1  APF
```

I would to add a column that contains the sum of the events tipye "APF" that have occured in the previous, lets say 12 hours (a parameter actually that I could vary).

Result expected:

```
          fechayhora        id tipo    number_of_APF_12h
1: 2017-03-21 11:03:00 A2_LR1_Z1  APF  0
2: 2017-05-03 10:34:00 A2_LR1_Z1  APF  0
3: 2017-05-17 08:52:00 A2_LR1_Z1  APF  0
4: 2017-05-17 10:46:00 A2_LR1_Z1  APF  1
5: 2017-05-17 14:23:00 A2_LR1_Z1  APF  2
6: 2017-05-17 17:29:00 A2_LR1_Z1  APF  3
```

Comment: Folks here will want to see some code showing you've tried this yourself first.

Comment: Hello @jdv this is the first post I made and actually I am learning programming in R; I've no clue what is the procedure of posting questions and not because I've not put my trials doesn't mean I've not tried before, however I've no clue how to do it, that's why I wrote the post. If this bothers you so much, better don't answer.

Comment: Perhaps you are unaware that StackOverflow requests that members review new questions and offer assistance for new users to help them learn how to best use the site. The idea is to help you create a question that is more likely to attract good answers, and be useful to other people in the future. Typically, you are expected to try and solve your problem yourself first. I suggest that you review the following references: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and especially https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that utilizes `purrr::map2_dbl()`. You can change the number of hours to whatever you'd like.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tibble))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(purrr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lubridate))

# Example data
df <- tribble(
  ~fechayhora,        ~id,       ~tipo,
  "2017-03-21 11:03:00", "A2_LR1_Z1",  "APF",
  "2017-05-03 10:34:00", "A2_LR1_Z1",  "APF",
  "2017-05-17 08:52:00", "A2_LR1_Z1",  "APF",
  "2017-05-17 10:46:00", "A2_LR1_Z1",  "APF",
  "2017-05-17 14:23:00", "A2_LR1_Z1",  "APF",
  "2017-05-17 17:29:00", "A2_LR1_Z1",  "APF"
)

# Convert fechayhora to date and add a column of the time difference
df <- df %>%
  mutate(fechayhora = as.POSIXct(fechayhora),
         minus_12   = fechayhora - hours(12))

# Map over fechayhora and minus_12
# For each (fechayhora, minus_12) pair, find all the dates between them
# and sum the logical vector that is returned
df <- df %>% mutate(
  number_of_APF_12h = map2_dbl(.x = fechayhora, 
                               .y = minus_12, 
                               .f = ~sum(between(df$fechayhora, .y, .x)) - 1))

df %>%
  select(fechayhora, number_of_APF_12h)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>            fechayhora number_of_APF_12h
#>                <dttm>             <dbl>
#> 1 2017-03-21 11:03:00                 0
#> 2 2017-05-03 10:34:00                 0
#> 3 2017-05-17 08:52:00                 0
#> 4 2017-05-17 10:46:00                 1
#> 5 2017-05-17 14:23:00                 2
#> 6 2017-05-17 17:29:00                 3
```

Comment: Hello Davis Vaughan !! It is perfect :) now I am trying the following without any succes (grouping by id and type of machine):
   
    df2 <- df2 %>%
      group_by(id,tipo) %>%
      mutate(
        number_of_APF_12h = map2_dbl(.x = fechayhora, 
                                     .y = minus_12, 
                                     .f = ~sum(between(df2$fechayhora, .y, .x)) - 
    1))%>%
     ungroup()

Comment: Or the same, trying with data.table:                                  
df=as.data.table(df)
df[,x:= map2_dbl(.x = fechayhora,.y = minus_12,.f = ~sum(between(df$fechayhora, .y, .x)) - 1),by=id]

Comment: @Martu, since this person basically did all the hard work for you, you should probably mark this as the "best" or "accepted" answer. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Actually i did that but the page sais as I have no 15 reputación it "cannot change anything"