# sum if the time difference is smaller than the value by id and by type

Tags: r, dataframe, time, datatable, purrr

Regarding this issue:
[Sum if the date difference is smaller than a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730181/sum-if-the-date-difference-is-smaller-than-a-value?answertab=active#tab-top)
Now I have the possibility to calculate the number of events that happened in the previous 12h thanks to @Davis Vaughan:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~fechayhora,        ~id,       ~tipo,
  "2017-03-17 08:03:00", "A",  "APF",
  "2017-05-17 10:34:00", "A",  "APF",
  "2017-05-17 12:52:00", "A",  "APF",
  "2017-05-17 08:52:00", "A",  "APP",
  "2017-05-17 10:52:00", "A",  "APP",
  "2017-05-17 10:46:00", "B",  "APP",
  "2017-05-17 14:23:00", "B",  "APP",
  "2017-05-17 17:29:00", "B",  "APF"
)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(fechayhora = as.POSIXct(fechayhora),
         minus_12   = fechayhora - hours(12))

df <- df %>% mutate(
  number_of_APF_12h = map2_dbl(.x = fechayhora, 
                               .y = minus_12, 
                               .f = ~sum(between(df$fechayhora, .y, .x)) - 
1))
```

Then I am trying to do the same but grouping by "id" and by "tipo" (type). I've tryed with data table and data frame, with no succed:

```
df=df[,number_of_failures_12h = map2_dbl(.x = fechayhora, 
                               .y = minus_12, 
                               .f = ~sum(between(df$fechayhora, .y, .x)) - 
1)),by=.(tipo,id)]
```

or

```
df <- df %>%
group_by(id,tipo)
%>% mutate(
  number_of_failure = map2_dbl(.x = fechayhora, 
                               .y = minus_12, 
                               .f = ~sum(between(df$fechayhora, .y, .x)) - 
1)) %>%
ungroup()
```

Result expected:

```
   fechayhora             id    tipo      n_APP   n_APF
   "2017-03-17 08:03:00", "A",  "APF",    0       0 
   "2017-05-17 10:34:00", "A",  "APF",    0       1
   "2017-05-17 12:52:00", "A",  "APF",    0       2
   "2017-05-17 08:52:00", "A",  "APP",    0       2
   "2017-05-17 10:52:00", "A",  "APP",    1       2  
   "2017-05-17 10:46:00", "B",  "APP",    0       0
   "2017-05-17 14:23:00", "B",  "APP",    1       0
   "2017-05-17 17:29:00", "B",  "APF"     0       0
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry, there is a lot of speculation

Comment: If you want, tell me what is not clear thank you

Comment: how did u get the expected output with dplyr as I am not able to

Comment: this is what i am trying to do, by it doesn't work: df=df[,number_of_failures_12h = map2_dbl(.x = fechayhora, 
                               .y = minus_12, 
                               .f = ~sum(between(df$fechayhora, .y, .x)) - 
1)),by=.(tipo,id)]

Comment: ahhh... the expected output I wrote it by hand, I am not being able to get it neither with data table, neither than dplyr :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a classier way, but this should do it:

```
# Auxiliary function
count_failures <- function(group, last_12, rowid, type) {
   group[1:rowid-1, ] %>% 
    filter(tipo %in% type & fechayhora >= last_12) %>% 
    nrow()
}

split_by_group <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  do(data = (.)) %>% 
  select(data) %>% 
  map(identity) %>% 
  .[[1]]

df_s <- split_by_group %>% 
  map(arrange, fechayhora) %>% 
  map(.f = function(x) { 
    x %>% 
      rowid_to_column() %>% 
      rowwise() %>% 
      mutate(n_APP = count_failures(x, minus_12, rowid, "APP"),
             n_APF = count_failures(x, minus_12, rowid, "APF")) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      select(-rowid)
      }) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 6
           fechayhora    id  tipo            minus_12 n_APP n_APF
               <dttm> <chr> <chr>              <dttm> <int> <int>
1 2017-03-17 08:03:00     A   APF 2017-03-16 20:03:00     0     0
2 2017-05-17 08:52:00     A   APP 2017-05-16 20:52:00     0     0
3 2017-05-17 10:34:00     A   APF 2017-05-16 22:34:00     1     0
4 2017-05-17 10:52:00     A   APP 2017-05-16 22:52:00     1     1
5 2017-05-17 12:52:00     A   APF 2017-05-17 00:52:00     2     1
6 2017-05-17 10:46:00     B   APP 2017-05-16 22:46:00     0     0
7 2017-05-17 14:23:00     B   APP 2017-05-17 02:23:00     1     0
8 2017-05-17 17:29:00     B   APF 2017-05-17 05:29:00     2     0
```

Comment: Hello @quartin ! thank you very much for answering, it is almost that, but with two columns as result: the number of n_failures type APP and the number of n failures type APF; that is for each line I would like to know how many events of the preivous types have occured...

Comment: I've edited the answer, can you please check if the output is what you want? Your expected output and your explanation of what you want don't seem to match...

Comment: @Martu I had a typo in the `group_by`. When editing the answer didn't copy crrectly. It's corrected now.